# Convert '229, 255, 66' to (229, 255, 66) in Python

Tags: python

I want to do a simple conversion of `u'229, 255, 66'` to `(229, 255, 66)`

Is there a very simple way to do this?  Or do I need to split, convert to int, etc...

Comment: The answer depends very much on the level of error checking you want to do. For example, do you want to ensure that it's a tuple of length 3? Duncan's literal_eval solution, while much safer than a raw eval(), allows negative numbers, tuples of any length, strings, irrational numbers, and more, so you may want to have additional checks. The split/int solution gives you a tuple of arbitrary length, containing only integers, but raises a ValueError if one of the terms isn't an integer. It also returns negative numbers. In case of errors, do you want to return the error position?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easy way is to use the function `ast.literal_eval()` which has none of the security issues of using `eval`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(u'229, 255, 66')
(229, 255, 66)
```

Answer (score 2):

Builtin function eval() will return a tuple, no splitting needed (as per your question).

> eval('299, 255, 66')

will return

> (229, 255, 66)

Comment: Eval is evil, ast.literal_eval() is safer.

Comment: Don't do this if the string comes from any source that is not completely trustworthy: without safeguards `eval` could just as easily reformat your disc as give you a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `split` on the comma, and use a list comprehension to apply `int` to the result:

```
In [1]: s = u'229, 255, 66'

In [2]: tuple(int(i) for i in  s.split(','))
Out[2]: (229, 255, 66)
```

`map` is equivalent to the list comprehension (but currently considered "less pythonic" to some. `eval(s)` will work but is considered dangerous, depending on where your string comes from.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
x = u'229, 255, 66'
p = tuple(map(int, x.split(',')))
```